# Why does my program stop after 3 wrong guesses?

Tags: python, loops

So i'm new to programming and I was trying to make a 'guess the number' program but it stops after 3 wrong guesses. I'm probably doing something really stupid so sorry if the question sounds dumb.

Thanks in advance

```
from random import *

number = randrange(1,100)

guess = int(input('Guess the number (between 1-100)'))

if guess == number:
    print('Well done!')

while guess > number:
    print('Lower')
    guess = int(input('Try again: '))

while guess < number:
    print('Higher')
    guess = int(input('Try again: '))
```

Comment: Now's a good time to learn [how to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
and 
[what is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)  
Step through your code and observe what each line of code does. 
Identify where your program differs from your expectations by comparing these intermediate results with expected results. 
Work backwards from there to narrow down the cause of the problem.

Comment: Your current code will check if the guess is larger than the number and keep asking for a new guess until it isn't. Then, it'll check if it's smaller than the number and keep asking for a new guess. What do you suppose will happen when `number = 50` and your guesses are `100, 99, 98, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4`? What about when your guesses are `100, 0, 99, 1, 98, 2`? Will your code work the way you expect when you give these inputs?

Comment: We expect you to also trace your code -- to do that initial debugging pass.  In each loop, print out the loop control values (`guess` and `number`), and make a unique label for each loop, so that you know exactly where your program goes at all times, and why.

Answer (score 1):

By having the three cases (equal, more than, less than) handled in separated blocks, once you get past one, you don't come back to it. For instance, the program checks for equality only once, and if it fails the first time, then it never checks again. You should put all three in one block.

```
from random import *    
number = randrange(1,100)    
max_attempts = 100    
for attempt in range(max_attempts):
    guess = int(input('Guess the number (between 1-100)'))
    if guess == number:
        print('Well done!')
        break
    if guess > number:
        print('Lower')
        continue  
    if guess < number
        print('Higher')
        continue
```

`break` means to stop the loop, and `continue` means to go on to the next iteration of the loop. I used a for-loop since that is guaranteed to halt.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you break out of a `while` loop, you can not revisit that loop again. I.E for `while guess > number`, as soon as the user guesses a number that is `<= number` then you will break out the loop and the program will move past it.

Instead use this code:

```
from random import *

number = randrange(1,100)

guess = int(input('Guess the number (between 1-100)'))

while guess != number:
    if guess < number:
        print('Higher')
    else: 
        print('Lower')

    guess = int(input('Try again: '))

print('Well done!')
```

This program runs the `while` loop when `guess != number`. This condition will break when `guess != number` is `False`, or in other words, when the user guesses the correct number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the while loops to this:

```py
while guess != number:
    if guess > number:
        print('Higher')
        guess = int(input('Try again: '))
    elif guess < number:
        print('Lower')
        guess = int(input('Try again: '))
```

Basically, previously, if the guess is smaller that the number, it starts the while loop, `while guess < number` However, when the guess is bigger, the while loop stops because the guess is no longer smaller than the number.

To fix this, create one while loop and, in that, check to see in the guess is bigger or smaller than the number.

You could therefore, remove the guess from each if statement, and put it at the end of the while loop, if that makes sense, like this:

```py
while guess != number:
    if guess > number:
        print('Lower')
    elif guess < number:
        print('Higher')
    guess = int(input('Try again: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple while loops makes your debugging more complicated without any gain.

I would suggest you to use a single while loop:

```
from random import *

number = randrange(1,100)
guessed = False

while not guessed:
    guess = int(input('Guess the number (between 1-100)'))        
    if guess > number:
        print('Lower')
    elif guess < number:
        print('Higher')    
    else:
        print('Well done!')
        guessed = True
```

Comment: Hi there,

if you found my code useful please don't forget upvoting it and/or choosing it as final answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very much of a programmer neither but I Have been using python regularly lately , although i'm not sure what causes this problem , you can try this alternative code that worked pretty well for me :

```
from random import *

number = randrange(1,100)

guess = int(input('Guess the number (between 1-100)'))

while True:
    if guess > number:
        print('Lower')
        guess = int(input('Try again: '))
    elif guess < number:
        print('Higher')
        guess = int(input('Try again: '))
    else:
        print('Well done!')
        break
```